# How do I retain form values upon submit for a <select> loop?

Tags: php

How do I retain form values upon submit for a  loop?

I've got something like this:

```
<?php
    printf ("<optgroup label=\"CATEGORIES\">");

    foreach ($category as $key => $val) {
    printf ("<option value=\"$key\">$val</option>");
    }
    printf ("</optgroup>");
?>
```

When hitting submit on another part of my form, it resets the values in the select to the top one. I want it to keep the same value. How? For things like input boxes I have this that works:

```
<option value="5" name="results" <?php if($_GET["results"] == '5'){  ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> >5</option>
```

This works because I'm not dynamically populating the dropdown from a database, so I don't need a loop to loop through values and populate the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf ("<optgroup label=\"CATEGORIES\">");

foreach ($category as $key => $val) {
  $option = '<option value="' . $key . '"';
  if ($_GET['select_name'] == $key) {
    $option .= ' selected="selected"';
  }
  $option .= ">$val</option>";

  print $option;
}
printf ("</optgroup>");
```

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on where the action for your submit button sends you.
You will need to get the values, most likely form $_POST and restore them in your form.
Otherwise you can use AJAX to submit the form and not worry about it being cleared.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($category as $key => $val) {
    $sel = ($key == $_GET['results']) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    printf ("<option value=\"$key\"$sel>$val</option>");
}
```

Basically, dynamically insert the selected attribute when/if you reach a $key value that was submitted.

Comment: This is correct and the most elegant solution thus far, however, don't forget to account for the situation when `$_GET['results']` is not set, the current code will only work during a postback.

Comment: Ah I get what you did. It doesn't work though. The selects name is "book", so I put "book" where you put "results" and it doesn't work. It retained values for 3 random options.